# Xorg Setting checking from Command Line

Tags: command-line, xorg, x11, xinerama

How do I determined, whether Xorg is using 
`Xinerama, DDC and Reduced Blanking` ??

Just adding few options in Xorg.conf is sufficient ?

If I have to check from command-line, then how can I check above mentioned settings ?

(I am using VIA chipset and Dell DELA07A monitor, Just in case this info required )

EDIT:

If I execute the command: `Xorg -extension ?`
It gives me the output as

```
[mi] Extension "?" is not recognized
[mi] Only the following extensions can be run-time disabled:
[mi]    Generic Events
[mi]    Composite
[mi]    DAMAGE
[mi]    DOUBLE-BUFFER
[mi]    DPMS
[mi]    GLX
[mi]    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[mi]    MIT-SHM
[mi]    RANDR
[mi]    RENDER
[mi]    SECURITY
[mi]    X-Resource
[mi]    XFIXES
[mi]    XINERAMA
[mi]    SELinux
[mi]    XTEST
[mi]    XVideo
```

As per the above output, I assume that it is possible to enable/disable extensions in runtime. Question is HOW ?
If it is really possible then I can enable/disable the XINERAMA extension as and when I want

I also assume that when XINERAMA is ON in dual-head then maximizing an open application will span on both monitor.
And when XINERAMA is off then maximizing an application will span to one monitor only. ( Correct me if I'm wrong )

Comment: `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` (for display `:0`). See also `xdpyinfo` for some information.

Comment: `xdpyinfo | egrep -i 'Xinerama|DDC|Reduced Blanking'` returns *XINERAMA* here.

Answer (score 2):

To check if Xinerama is enabled:

```
xdpyinfo| grep XINERAMA
```

To get the settings of Xinerama extension:

```
xdpyinfo -ext XINERAMA
```

About reduced blanking: you can show the modes the Xserver knows about by calling `xrandr --verbose` and examining the current one. Using the `cvt` tool you can generate modelines with/without reduced blanking for your desired resolution and compare those to the ones you see in xrandr output.

DDC information: I am not really sure. Maybe have a look at the X log file. With the mentioned `xrandr --verbose` you can also see the EDID of connected monitors.

Update: I just found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Resolution where a tool called `ddcprobe` is mentioned. So - without knowing it - I want to add that to the list.